# Coins in probability

Tags: probability

There are 8 erns. The first cotain 1 coin the second 2 coins, the third 3...adn the 8th - 8 coins. They are all identical coins, except one which is a gold coin. If one picks all the coins in urn number 4 (which has 4 coins) what is the probability that one of the coins be the gold coin?

I thought that as with every choice of one coin there is a 1 to 36 chance of it being the gold coin the answer would be 1 to 9 when choosing all the coins in urn number 4.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts. Also, indicate what we know about the placement of the gold coin (i.e. is it equally likely to be any one of the coins or not)

Comment: isn't it just 8!/(36)^8?

Comment: Isn't it just 1/8 because there are 8 choices for which urn gets the gold coin and then you fill up the urns with the identical non-gold coins. So you have a 1/8 chance of gold coin being in urn 4.

Comment: You have failed to provide an important piece of information.  Is each coin equally likely to be the gold coin?  Or is each urn equally likely to contain the gold coin, and each coin within the selected urn equally likely to be the gold coin?  These are two different situations resulting in two different answers.

Comment: @PTrivedi I don't think it's equally likely that the gold coin is in each of the urns. The first urn only has 1 coin in it and the eighth urn has 8 coins in it, so intuitively it'd be more likely that the gold coin is in urn eight. However, we don't know if the coin is equally likely to be any one of the coins.

Comment: @lulu see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First see the comment of lulu, immediately following the posted question.  As suggested by that comment, the problem is ambiguous.  In order to solve the problem, you need information about what (random) method was used to determine which urn would receive the gold coin.  Based on my reading of the problem, there are $2$ equally plausible ways that the gold coin might have been placed in one of the urns.

- The gold coin was grouped in with the $35$ other coins.  Then, at random, $k$ of those coins were selected for urn $k ~: k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}.$ 
  The computations in the answer of Paul D. P. Blum explore this presumption, arriving at the computation of $~\displaystyle \frac{4}{36} = \frac{1}{9}.$
- One of the $8$ urns was chosen at random.  The gold coin was assigned to this randomly chosen urn.  Then, the remaining $35$ coins were distributed so that urn $k$ would contain $k$ coins, one of which might or might not be gold.
  Under this presumption, the probability is instead $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{8}.$

Where I disagree with the answer of Paul D. P. Blum, is his (apparent) assertion that the question posted by the OP (i.e. original poster) clearly specifies explanation-1 above, rather than explanation-2.  I see nothing in the posted question that would exclude explanation-2.

Of course, if you accept (after the fact) that the intended answer is $~\displaystyle \frac{4}{36} = \frac{1}{9}$, you can reverse-engineer that the problem composer intended explanation-1.

Explanation-1 might also be reverse-engineered by **meta-cheating**.  That is, you ask yourself, which intended explanation would create a problem with the better educational value for a student new to Probability Theory.

Generally, in problems of this type, information is given that the urns are not equally likely to be the pertinent urn.  Then, you often have the student learning, by making a mistake which is then corrected, that you have to pay attention to how the gold coin was distributed.

Here, assuming that the OP did not negligently omit a critical piece of information, you have instead that the problem composer negligently omitted a key piece of information.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer. Regarding the first option you mentioned - I don't see any choosing being necessary, for all the coins are a like, so there is no need of any choosing. They are not individually identifiable, they are all alike. I would think the formulation would then be not in terms of choosing an urn, but the probability of picking the gold coin at random. That would be 1 of 36. So i understand why choosing urn number 4 would be 1 of 9, but I could also think that there is some conditional probability here. After picking the first one, the second one has 1 to 35 chance.

Comment: @Cantor There is a simpler way of considering the first option.  Instead of looking at the individual events of it being the 1st coin in Urn-4, and then the 2nd coin in Urn-4, and so on, it is far better to consider the event that the gold coin is in a group of $4$ coins, chosen at random... **any** $4$ coins out of $36$.  Such an event would have to have a probability of $(4/36)$, bypassing any need to consider different events / conditional events.

Answer (score 0):

The urns do nothing special to separate the coins, unless a different question were asked. Assuming (as one must with no other information) that each urn has the same probability of producing the gold coin. There are 1+2+...+8=(8*9)/2=36 possible coins to be the gold coin (a denominator). There then are four coins you choose (the numerator). Thus as you mentioned, there are 4/36, 1/9 possible ways to actually have a gold coin in the 4-urn.

Comment: please remove the answer from your question.

Comment: My answer partially disagrees with yours.

Comment: @user2661923 However, the OP did not say an urn was chosen at random to your second point of 1/8 (sorry can't get the fraction LaTex to work). The specific question mentioned that he chose the four coin urn (different from any other Urn). So then, it does indeed seem my answer (and OP's answer) must be chosen. I don't have enough reputation so I am not allowed to comment on your other post! (:

Comment: "...However, the OP did not say an urn was chosen at random..." : **and** the OP did **not** say that it is **not the case** that an urn was chosen at random.  This is the point that lulu and I were both making.  There is nothing in the first paragraph of the OP's posting that would **in any way** indicate which of the $2$ options for distributing the gold coin into an urn, which I discussed, is the **intended** option.  So, one is forced to conclude that the problem is ambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is 1 divided by 8 factorial, i.e. 1/8!

The ! stands for factorial.

This is the same as (1/1) * (1/2) * (1/3) * ... *(1/8)

Comment: This is not the right answer.

Comment: How did you get to this number? can you elaborate on it? (it is wrong, but it is important to understand your thinking in order to correct it)